# Ocaml: using list.length

Tags: list, ocaml

I am trying to find the length of a list in ocaml.

I call a function first called

> ```
> > let get_list_length e in   
> > print_list_length out x
> ```

the actual code in get_list_length is where I am confused. The "e" is a list of "commands" and I want to find the length of all the "commands".

> let get_list_length(e:values) : unit =
>     match e with
>           let x =
>          list.length(e);;

So my e is the list of "commands" which are a bunch of values specified in my grammar file. I am confused about how to get the length of the list since e is a list of values and I want the length of that list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the length of a list is simple:

```
List.length my_list
```

Your `get_list_length` function can be as simple as:

```
let get_list_length e = List.length e
```

or more simply:

```
let get_list_length = List.length
```

As you currently have defined it, `get_list_length` returns type `unit` so you won't get anything useful from it.  You are also using match incorrectly, it's usually used like this:

```
match e with something -> do something
| something_else -> do something_else
```